# Is this a mistake in calculating probabilities?

Tags: probability, proof-explanation, conditional-probability

I'm reading the solution from my lecture note:

> [image]

In my understanding, $$\begin{cases}P\left(\mu_{t}=m_{2} | \mu_{t-1}=m_{1}\right)+P\left(\mu_{t}=m_{1} | \mu_{t-1}=m_{1}\right) = P(\mu_{t-1}=m_{1}) \\ P\left(\mu_{t}=m_{1} | \mu_{t-1}=m_{2}\right) + P\left(\mu_{t}=m_{2} | \mu_{t-1}=m_{2}\right) = P(\mu_{t-1}=m_{2}) \end{cases}$$

Then $$\begin{cases}P\left(\mu_{t}=m_{2} | \mu_{t-1}=m_{1}\right)+p = P(\mu_{t-1}=m_{1}) \\ P\left(\mu_{t}=m_{1} | \mu_{t-1}=m_{2}\right) + q = P(\mu_{t-1}=m_{2}) \end{cases}$$

Finally, $$\begin{cases}P\left(\mu_{t}=m_{2} | \mu_{t-1}=m_{1}\right)= P(\mu_{t-1}=m_{1}) -p\\ P\left(\mu_{t}=m_{1} | \mu_{t-1}=m_{2}\right) = P(\mu_{t-1}=m_{2})-q \end{cases}$$

As such, the author  is wrong in asserting $$\begin{cases}
{P\left(\mu_{t}=m_{2} | \mu_{t-1}=m_{1}\right)=1-p} \\
{P\left(\mu_{t}=m_{1} | \mu_{t-1}=m_{2}\right)=1-q}
\end{cases}$$

Could you please confirm if my observation is correct? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is correct. This
$$P\left(\mu_{t}=m_{2} | \mu_{t-1}=m_{1}\right)+P\left(\mu_{t}=m_{1} | \mu_{t-1}=m_{1}\right) = P(\mu_{t-1}=m_{1})$$
is incorrect. For any events $A$ and $B$,
$$P(A|B) + P(A^c|B) = 1,$$
where $A^c$ denotes the complement of $A$. This is because no matter what happened (i.e., no matter what $B$ is), with certainty either $A$ occurs or $A$ does not occur.

In your case, either $\mu_t = m_1$ or $\mu_t = m_2$; nothing else can occur. You can verify this with Bayes' rule, $P(A|B) = P(A\cap B) / P(B)$, and setting $A = \{\mu_t = m_1\}, B = \{\mu_{t-1} = m_1\}.$